# Spring-Boot : Searching in existing Index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to make an app where i search documents in an existing Index in ElasticSearch using Spring-Boot. I searched in documentation i didn't find any information about connecting to existing indexes. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/…. You can define the index to be access by annotating you Entity with @Document passing the param indexName with the name of the index you want to use.

```
@Document(indexName = "people")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    // …
}
```